# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'bindings'

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to call this PowerShell script from a C# Application.  I have included the `System.Management.Automation` reference.  The parameters are passed in as part of the script parameters.  Although I pass in all the required parameters, it doesn't appear to be setting the `-Bindings` parameter although I am passing in the values that are required to build that parameter value inside the script during execution.

Here is the simple PowerShell script:

```bsh
Param(
    $WebSiteName,
    $Type,
    $HostName,
    $Port,
    $IPAddress="*",
    $PhysicalPath
)

$BindInfo = $IPAddress + ":" + $port + ":" + $hostname
New-Item IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName -Bindings @{
    protocol="http";
    bindingInformation=$BindInfo
} -PhysicalPath $PhysicalPath
New-WebBinding -Name $WebSiteName -Protocol $Type -HostHeader ("www." +
    $HostName) -IPAddress $IPAddress -Port $port
```

Here is the C# console application code:

```cs
string text = @"{path}..\CreateSite.ps1 -WebSite testPowershell -Type http - HostName testpowershell.com -Port 80 -IPAddress 10.0.0.4 -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\testpowershell -bindings 10.0.0.4:80:testpowershell.com";
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
    // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(text);
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
        // object may be present here. check for null to prevent potential NRE.
        if (outputItem != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }
    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Error");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

I'm not sure why the `-Bindings` parameter is not being set although I pass in the necessary info when calling the script.

```
-Bindings @{
    protocol="http";
    bindingInformation=$BindInfo
}
```

Comment: Because `-bindings` is not one of the parameters of [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh it is, if using the WebAdministration module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/powershell/powershell-snap-in-creating-web-sites-web-applications-virtual-directories-and-application-pools Op: did you import that module into your powershell instance? Doesn't look like it. You may also try just using  New-WebBinding after creating a new site

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I've updated the script to include 'Import-Module "WebAdministration"' just after the parameter list in the script.  Now the error is: "{A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'New-WebBinding'.}"

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks for your  input as it was 'part' of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to figure out what the issue was with getting this script to work.

1. First I had to include the "Import-Module WebAdministration" in the PowerShell Script.
2. I had to use "PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter()" instead of "PowerShellInstance.AddParameter()".  This is what actually passed the parameters successfully into the script execution.

   string text = @"C:\CreateSite.ps1";

   ```
       using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
       {
           // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
           // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
           PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(text);
           PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("WebSiteName", @"RichSite69");
           PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("Type", @"http");
           PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("HostName", @"RichSite69.com");
           PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("Port", @"80");
           PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("PhysicalPath", @"C:\inetpub\richsite69");
           PowerShellInstance.Commands.AddParameter("IPAddress", @"10.0.0.4");
           //  -WebSite 'testPowershell' -Type 'http' -HostName 'testpowershell.com' -Port 80 -IPAddress '10.0.0.4' -'
           Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
           foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
           {
               // if null object was dumped to the pipeline during the script then a null
               // object may be present here. check for null to prevent poDtential NRE.
               if (outputItem != null)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString() + "\n");
               }
           }
           Console.WriteLine();
           foreach (var error in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
           {
               Console.Write(error.ToString());
           }
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   ```